# Application of Brouwer fixed point theorem, why is compactness not required here??

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Define a map $K:X_n \to X_n$ where $X=\text{span}(v_1, ..., v_n)$
where $v_i$ are basis functions some Hilbert space $H$. So $X_n$ is finite-dimensional.

$B_r(0)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centred at $0$ in $X_n$.

> (after some calculations)... Therefore, $K$ is locally Lipschitzian and satisfies $K(\overline{B_R(0)}) \subset \overline{B_R(0)}$, thus Brouwer's fixed point theorem tells us there is a fixed point.

Now, why does Brouwer apply here? For Banach spaces doesn't one require compactness of $K(\overline{B_R(0)})$ in $X_n$? Or do we not need it cause of the finite-dimensional nature of $X_n$?

Comment: Note the bars over $B_R(0)$: This means closed ball :) For Banach spaces, this goes by the name of the Schauder fixed point theorem.

Comment: But "bounded + closed = compact" only in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline{B_R(0)}$ is compact, since $X_n$ is finite-dimensional. Since $K$ is locally Lipschitz, it is continuous, and hence $K(\overline{B_R(0)})$ is compact too. But for Brouwer's theorem,  we only need the continuity, and that $K(\overline{B_R(0)}) \subset \overline{B_R(0)}$.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realise closed bounded sets in all finite-dimensional spaces were compact. Thought it was only $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thanks

Comment: @matt.x: The induced topology on a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space makes it homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, yes. It's not true in general that a closed, bounded subspace of an arbitrary metric space is compact.

Comment: @matt.x: If you have a $T_{2}$ topology on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{N}$ for which vector addition and scalar multiplication are continuous, then the topology is equivalent to the usual Euclidean topology. In particular, all normed topologies and all inner-product topologies on finite-dimensional spaces over the real numbers are equivalent; and, all normed topologies and all inner-product topologies on finite-dimensional spaces over the complex numbers are equivalent. It's a useful result to know about.

Comment: Thanks @T.A.E., yeah that is useful to know.

Comment: @DanielFischer so $K:X_n \to X_n$ also has a fixed point right? because you say compactness is not required. And $X_n$ should be a closed space.

Comment: @matt.x For Brouwer's theorem, you need something homeomorphic to a closed ball in an $\mathbb{R}^n$, so something compact, call it $B$, and a continuous map $f\colon B \to B$. $f(B)$ is then automatically compact as a continuous image of a compact set, you don't need to mention the compactness of $f(B)$ explicitly. That's what I meant.